# Kafka increasing consumer lag

Tags: apache-kafka, elk

I have ELK stack installed with Kafka on Docker containers. There is lag between incoming logs and consuming logs that is increasing, and offset reading speed is not enough.
Kafka have only one topic. I tried different combinations of number of partitions in Kafka and pipelines in Logstash, also various combinations of batch.size, delay, consumer_threads parameters and it almost makes no difference.

Hardware is 6 cores CPU, memory is 350 Gb, RAM is 24 Gb, Java heap size is 12 Gb.

Logstash configuration for pipeline:

```
input {
  kafka {
    topics => "mytopic"
    bootstrap_servers => "bootstrap_server:9092"
    codec => "cef"
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
    decorate_events => true
    consumer_threads => 6
    max_poll_records => 2000
    fetch_max_bytes => 209715200
    max_partition_fetch_bytes => 25165824
    fetch_max_wait_ms => 100
    session_timeout_ms => 600000
    heartbeat_interval_ms => 200000
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Logstash pipelines list:

```
- pipeline.id: pipe1
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"
  pipeline.batch.size: 500
  pipeline.batch.delay: 5
  pipeline.workers: 2

- pipeline.id: pipe2
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"
  pipeline.batch.size: 500
  pipeline.batch.delay: 5
  pipeline.workers: 2

- pipeline.id: pipe3
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"
  pipeline.batch.size: 500
  pipeline.batch.delay: 5
  pipeline.workers: 2
```

Kafka config is default with 6 partitions.

I want to get rid of lag on all partitions, how can I do that? I tried hundreds various configurations of parameters shown above, but lag is increasing anyway. Can it be issue with hardware?

Comment: Did you check the consumer group status, is it active/rebalancing?, is the lag consumed slowly or is it stagnant? you can check it via `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server kafka-broker:9092 --describe   --state --group <your_consumer_group>`

Comment: At the start consumers are rebalancing succesfuly, but when it's active I have ennormous increasing of lag

Comment: did it reach stable state?, any errors in the kafka broker logs, or log stash, maybe there is a serialization issue or something, the key point to pin point the main issue, is the consumer totally stuck can't even process a single message, then it is not related to resources, if it is consuming but very slow then you can dig deeper in the resources

Comment: Yep, Consumers are working but very slowly. While starting or working there are 0 errors. As you said, now I'm trying to find the main issue.

Comment: I'd try using Kafka Connect instead of logstash. Otherwise, more frequent polls can reduce lag, not bigger ones... However, you're starting at the latest offset so there shouldn't be any lag when the consumer starts

Comment: I tried a lot of configurations, with different delay and size parametrs. A grown of offsets was insignificant